# Isolated committing of transaction in SQL

Tags: sql, transactions

I have a n-tier C# ASP .Net application server which uses stored procedures to communicate with the database.

I have a service layer which rolls back all ADO .net transactions if an exception is thrown, using TransactionScope.requiresNew.

In my stored procedure, I want to track login attempt numbers, so we want to keep the transaction framework as is, but want to have an isolated transaction which we commit.

How do I do this?

I have tried using a new TransactionScope.RequiresNew in our data layer, but this has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange - RequiresNew in the inner (Logging) TransactionScope should work.

In the below nested transaction, TransactionScopeOption.Suppress or TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew both work for me - the inner transaction is committed (Dal2.x), and the outer one aborted (Dal1.x).

```
    try
    {
        using (TransactionScope tsOuter = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
        {
            DAL1.Txn1();
            using (TransactionScope tsLogging = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
            {
                DAL2.Txn2();
                tsLogging.Complete();
            }
            throw new Exception("Big Hairy Exception");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Edit : Mixing TransactionScope and explicit T-SQL transactions is to be avoided - this is stated in the same link you've referenced viz http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973865.aspx, quoted below

TransactionScopes manage transaction escalation quite intelligently - they will use the (e.g. DTC will only be used if the transactions span multiple databases or resources - e.g. SQL and MSMQ). They also work with the SQL 2005+ Lightweight transactions, so multiple connections to the same database will also be managed within a transaction without the overheads of DTC.

IMHO the decision as to whether to use Suppress vs RequiresNew will depend on whether you need to do your auditing within a transaction at all - RequiresNew for an isolated txn, vs Suppress for none.

> When using System.Transactions,
>   applications should not directly
>   utilize transactional programming
>   interfaces on resource managers—for
>   example the T-SQL BEGIN TRANSACTION or
>   COMMIT TRANSACTION verbs, or the
>   MessageQueueTransaction() object in
>   System.Messaging namespace, when
>   dealing with MSMQ. Those mechanisms
>   would bypass the distributed
>   transaction management handled by
>   System.Transactions, and combining the
>   use of System.Transactions with these
>   resource manager "internal"
>   transactions will lead to inconsistent
>   results .... Never mix the two

Comment: After a bit of reading (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973865.aspx), Suppress has no transaction at all. It also does not use the ambient transaction which is what I want.  Not sure if I would prefer a transaction or not. I have one in my stored procedure (BEGIN TRANSACTION, COMMIT)...

Comment: Hi Russell - I've edited my original post as my comment was too big. If you can. Since it sounds like you have a strategy for controlling transactions from your .NET code (e.g. Service or Business Tiers), would recommend that you drop the BEGIN TRAN / COMMIT TRAN from your sprocs - TransactionScope supercedes this.